# Dynamics 365 JavaScript - moveNext (business process flow) function on dirty form. How to prevent double saving?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

When i use javascript function to move next stage (formContext.data.process.**moveNext**(callbackFunction))

on a dirty form it requires fist to save the form.
So I save the form and call **moveNext** function.

**moveNext** function itself causing second saving -  so the process is slow

But when i click the button "Move Next" on a dirty form - it saves  and move next in one save - so the process is faster

How can I prevent this double saving when moving next on a dirty form with javascript?
Can I call the same function that the Button uses?

Comment: how about you first call save function and on successCallback you can call moveNext `formContext.data.save(saveOptions).then(successCallback, errorCallback);` Note: save function is async.

Comment: this is exactly what I do ). it causes 2 save transaction. I want to avoid this

Comment: I think you cannot avoid these 2 Transactions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a bit hacky, but you could try this:

```
if (formContext.data.getIsDirty()) {
    formContext.data.process._getProcessManager().moveToNextStage().then(callback);
} else {
    formContext.data.process.moveNext(callback);
}
```

Comment: it works. but it's not the supported way. but maybe I will use it :-)